# Which is the right way to calculate number of points of an image?

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing, pixel

View.Bounds gave me values of (0.0, 0.0, 375.0, 667.0) to help calculate view dimensions. And CGImage, size of bitmap gave me pixel count of 490 - pixel width and  751 - pixel height. I don't understand why I get UIView bounds content size less than CGImage pixel width and height when scale factor gave me value of 2. But how can I calculate number of points from the dimensions ? How can I take out 375.0 and 667.0 and calculate ? Below code helped me to get view dimensions and scale factor.

```
let ourImage: UIImage? = imageView.image
let viewBounds = view.bounds
print("\(viewBounds)")
var scale: CGFloat = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
print("\(scale)")
```

And this is the code I worked to receive pixel height and width of 490 * 751.

```
public init?(image: UIImage) {
    guard let cgImage = image.CGImage else { return nil }

    // Redraw image for correct pixel format
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()

    var bitmapInfo: UInt32 = CGBitmapInfo.ByteOrder32Big.rawValue
    bitmapInfo |= CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue & CGBitmapInfo.AlphaInfoMask.rawValue

    width = Int(image.size.width)
    height = Int(image.size.height)
 .... }
```

Or can I use (pixelWidth * 2 + pixelHeight * 2) as to calculate number of points ? I need to calculate or fix number of points (n) to substitute in further equation of image segmentation using active contour method.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do.  Why exactly are you trying to calculate the size of an image?  It shouldn't matter.  This sounds like an XY problem.

Comment: I need to figure out or set number of points in an image to use it in further calculations of an image segmentation algorithm, need to use the value in the equation. So how can I proceed to calculate or set number of points ?

Comment: Oh.  So... the image view won't resize to the image's size.  The image view will present a representation of the image that is scaled to the image view's size... but the image itself may very well be a different size (it may even have a different aspect ratio).  `image.size.width` and `image.size.height` give you the true measurements of the actual image.

Comment: Oh, Okay. Working on the given suggestion. Thank you very much.

Comment: Great, the answer works for me. Can you please provide it as an answer so I can select it and mention this question as answered ? Once again Thank you, I was confused size and bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An image view does not resize to match the image property you set to it.  Nor does the image you set resize to match the image view's frame.

Instead, the image view presents a representation of that image scaled to whatever size matches the image view (based on the rules you pick, aspect fit, aspect fill, scale to fill, others, etc).

So the *actual* size of the image is exactly whatever is returns from the image's `size` property.

To get the actual image's actual width, use:

```
image.size.width
```

Likewise, to get the actual image's actual height, use:

```
image.size.height
```